# Can I make pylibmc work with python 3.2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memcached

I installed some dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.2-dev
sudo apt-get install libmemcached-dev
```

And tried to:

```
pip install pylibmc
```

while in virtualenv with my python 3.2

but had this:

```
_pylibmcmodule.c:77:9: error: ‘PylibMC_Client’ has no member named ‘ob_type’
_pylibmcmodule.c:1812:39: error: ‘PyInt_Type’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_pylibmcmodule.c:1841:53: error: ‘PylibMC_Client’ has no member named ‘ob_type’
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

How can I fix that?
(it works with python 2.7)

Comment: I guess you need to start porting, see http://python3porting.com/cextensions.html

Comment: @MartijnPieters, test it if you want =) https://github.com/pashinin/pylibmc/tree/python3-test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: It looks like it is working in "master" but not released yet.

I wrote some python 3 support - [see my repo branch](https://github.com/pashinin/pylibmc/tree/python3-test)

I modified tests but still have a couple failing:

```
1. "test_touch" (test_client.py)
```

It fails for me for both python 2 and 3. Even for unchanged code. (Looks like my memcache problem - don't know)

```
>       ok_(self.mc.touch(touch_test, 5))
E       SystemError: error return without exception set
```

---

```
2. "test_cas" (test_client.py)
```

Fails only for python 3. Python 2 is ok.

```
>           rv, cas = mc.gets(k)
E           ValueError: gets without cas behavior
```

It might be caused by saving Integer objects with `pickle`.
The responsible code is:

```
} else if (PyLong_Check(value_obj)) {
    serialized->flags |= PYLIBMC_FLAG_LONG;
    PyObject* tmp = PyNumber_Long(value_obj);
    store_val = PyObject_Bytes(tmp);
    Py_DECREF(tmp);
```

I can't use it in python 3 because `PyObject_Bytes` [generates an error](http://docs.python.org/3.2/c-api/object.html?highlight=pyobject_bytes#PyObject_Bytes) :

```
>       ok_(mc.set(k, 0))
E       TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

---

I run tests like this:

```
py.test tests/test_client.py
```

Comment: Very cool! Next step would be to make the tests work on both Python 2 and 3, so you can verify your work against the existing test suite!